# Basic probability questions

Tags: probability

How is P(A , B) different from P(A $\cap$ B)? I'm genuinely curious as to why one might prefer one over the other.

Also as far as some probability P (A | B , C) goes, what is the order of operations i.e., is it P (A | (B , C)) or P ((A | B) , C)? Or are they both similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $\Pr(A|B,C)$ is an *abbreviation* for $\Pr(A|(B\cap C))$. Since $B\cap C=C\cap B$, there is no precedence issue.

Sometimes $\Pr(A,B)$ is used as an abbreviation for $\Pr(A\cap B)$, but that is an uncommon practice. By way of contrast, one bumps often into the conditional probability version mentioned in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Note that  $P(A,B)$ is equal to $P(A\cap B)$.

P((A|B), C) is meaningless.